# I am not able to filter traces/message field properties

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am putting json text in traces/message field. I could not select properties in message feild using REST API $select.

The following is using Query Analytics. I want to do the same with REST API call.
Any idea?

traces
|extend d = parsejson(message)
| project d.name

Comment: Why are you putting json text in the trace and message fields as opposed to using custom properties and metrics? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#properties. Your approach kind of defeats the purpose of Application Insights.

Comment: I disagree. The power of Analytics allows you to not think beforehand of the stuff you want to query on, but rather use Application Insights to trace what seems to be relevant at the time (even as free text), and extract it later to meaningful data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Application Insights REST API - just compose your query and slap it on the URL. Here's your query running on the [DEMO APP](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&query=traces%0A%7Cextend%20d%20%3D%20parsejson(message)%20%0A%7C%20project%20d.name%20) (returning all nulls of course, but the syntax works).

Comment: Thanks Eran. It helped. if i want to use the REST API queries as part of the applciaiton logic(ie. in Java), are there classes to form these queries easily? or should I maingtain these URL strings and do string formatting?

Comment: Glad to have helped. Right now there isn't any class support for these queries, best strategy would be to test the query in your application's Analytics portal and then use the query string in the REST API